# Error reading UInt16 from BinaryReader

Tags: vb.net, unicode, binary, ascii, uint16

Why does this work

```
Dim mem As New MemoryStream()
Dim bin As New BinaryWriter(mem)
bin.Write(CUShort(1000))
Dim read As New BinaryReader(New MemoryStream(mem.ToArray))
MsgBox(read.ReadInt16)
```

The message box give me 1000 which is right. Then I try to use this

```
Dim mem As New MemoryStream()
Dim bin As New BinaryWriter(mem)
bin.Write(CUShort(1000))
Dim s As String = ASCII.GetString(mem.ToArray)
Dim read As New BinaryReader(New MemoryStream(ASCII.GetBytes(s)))
MsgBox(read.ReadInt16)
```

It gives me 831 which is incorrect. Now I try it with Unicode encoding. It works. But I want to use ASCII. Why is this, and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you experience happens because of the way the .NET Runtime stores strings in memory, and because different encodings have a different set of characters.

A `(U)Short` is represented in memory by two bytes. When you call `ASCII.GetString()` the byte array is interpreted as coming from an ASCII string and is therefore converted into a UTF-16 string. This conversion is performed because UTF-16 is the encoding that ***all*** strings are stored as in memory by the .NET runtime.

`Encoding.Unicode` however is the same as UTF-16, so (at this point) no extra conversion is needed to store the string in memory. The byte array is just copied and marked as a string, ***thus*** you get the very same bytes and the same `UShort`.

This fiddle illustrates what I'm talking about: https://dotnetfiddle.net/p4EKn9

Comment: +1 Thank you so much for clarifying this. I will make sure to use Unicode encoding for this purpose now.

Comment: @Adam : Glad I could help! This doesn't mean that you cannot use other encodings in your applications, but for the purpose of converting it _back_ into a `UShort` you should stick to Unicode. Good luck!

Comment: The fiddle was very useful, I can now fix many errors within my code. :)